# update state for only one item in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am showing and hiding description on an item which is managed through state. The only problem is I am managing this state for all mapped items on my page which means the state will apply to all items. How can I only manage it for one item inside wrapped items?

Here is example of what I have done.

Here I set the state to not show the description:

```
this.state = {
        show: false
    }
```

On click it will show the description, which I did like this:

```
<div className="mx-auto pb-3">
    {this.state.show ? <div><p className="mb-6 pt-3 text-center">
        {node.description.description}
    </p></div> : null}
</div>
```

As mentioned above this applies to all mapped items which is wrapped like this:

```
 <div className="row mx-auto">
 {this.state.allProducts.map(({ node }) => {
....
 })}
</div>
```

And here is my onClick function

```
<div className="mx-auto">
    <p className="prd-desc-option" onClick={() => { this.setState({ show: 
    !this.state.show }) }}>{this.state.show ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} Description
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your state variable should be an array or object that matches the items you are controlling. I mean for example object keys much match the item ids that you are tracking as hidden or visible

Comment: Good one @ozgur, I have been thinking about that . But how would I go about controlling this on my onClick?

Comment: how many items are you controlling? Can you give some more details?

Comment: Its an array of items received from graphql query, its not a fixed amount. This can always change depends how much is added by the user in the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manage the `show` attribute on the `allProducts` level and then based you condition on it:

```
<div className="row mx-auto">
  {this.state.allProducts.map(({ node }) => {
    <div className="mx-auto pb-3">
    {node.show ? 
      <div><p className="mb-6 pt-3 text-center">
        {node.description.description}
      </p></div> : null}
    </div>
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand this reply. Can you please elaborate based on my snippets above?

Comment: like @Striped said. put a `show` property in your product `object`. like `allProducts =[ {id: '1', name: 'example', description: 'example', show: 'true'}]`

Comment: This looks like the simplest and best solution

Comment: Ok I managed to add the show property on my product but because I am not using state with node.show I can't get my onClick to work. I have updated my original post above with the onClick function. How would I go about doing this? Surely I must be using props then right?

Comment: You still have a global show for all of your items. You need to have a show property on **each** items.

Comment: Yep that is the case currently. Just trying to understand how the conditional will work now? Based on props right? @Striped

Comment: This is not the case according to your code, there is still a `this.state.show` and a `this.state. allProducts` but, again you should have `this.state.allProducts` with a show property on **each** product and then check for `this.state.allProducts[x].show`.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, but would I need to add this when mapping over my products? I have created new snippet here not to be confused with above: https://www.codepile.net/pile/yqG616NV

Comment: You should split your code into two components a ProductList handling the list of node and a Product with an internal state `show` handling the node. See here for a sample https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-sea-x6sli